# O Localhost do wamp no firefox não funciona

Tags: firefox

Boa tarde a todos, tenho o pacote mysql e o wamp instalado no meu computador e escolhi o firefox como padrão para abrir no localhost do wamp. Fiz todo o procedimento para deixar o icone dele verde, mudei as portas do apache, desconectei o skype etc. Depois que eu consegui deixar tanto o mysql quanto o wamp verde mesmo assim quando eu tento abrir o arquivo index.php do localhost e o phpmyadmin no firexfox, não aparece nada, nenhuma mensagem, simplesmente a tela do firefox fica branca. Segue abaixo o print screem do pc para ilustrar o problema. Se alguém puder me ajudar para aparecer as interfaces do localhost e do admin fico grato. Vlw.

[image: printscreen localhost]

Comment: Você mudou as portas ? então acesse usando `localhost:PORTA` exemp: `localhost:8080` a porta 80 não precisa ser inserida mas se você usar outra precisa. detalhe, você pode mudar a porta no skype e permanecer usando a 80 apenas com localhost, [Alterar Porta Skype](http://edsonredes.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/tirar-o-skype-da-porta-80.html)

Comment: coloquei o endereço localhost com o numero da porta que foi mudada e deu esta mensagem estranha no print http://i.stack.imgur.com/KunOq.jpg. Eu mudei a porta seguinto o tutorial deste site: http://www.accelerated-ideas.com/perguntas-e-respostas/programas/como-instalar-wamp-server-instalado-mysql-773645-spage.aspx Antes quando só tinha o wamp instalado funcionava normal. Não sei se é problema do firefox ou conflito dos dois programas. Eu queria saber também aonde eu posso baixar os arquivos php do localhost e do phpmyadmin, não sei se estou com todos na pasta raiz www.

Comment: Tentou criar um arquivo de teste e acessar ele?

Comment: Sim, coloquei um html na pasta www e testei porem o firefox continua com a tela branca,talvez seja problema do firefox

Comment: testou em outros browsers? o que tem na index.php?

Comment: Se você digitar http://127.0.0.1 funciona ?

Answer (score -1):

Leonardo, caso você utilize o Skype, ele usa a porta 80, Você podera ir em:

> Ferramentas > Opções > Avançado > Conexão > Demarque a opção "Use as
>   portas 80 e  443 como conexões de entradas adcionais"

caso você ultiliza o servidor IIS ele tambem usa a porta 80 por Defalut, me informe a versão do seu Windows e a versão do seu Wamp Server, talvez eu possa lhe ajudar melhor!

Comment: Wamp server 2.5

Comment: windows 7 home premium 64 bits

Comment: mysql notifier 1.1.6

Comment: Mudei a porta padrão para 8080 do IIS e testei o localhost do firefox e deu a seguinte mensagem: Não é possível conectar-se

O Firefox não conseguiu estabelecer uma conexão com o servidor localhost.

    Este site pode estar temporariamente fora do ar ou sobrecarregado. Tente de novo em alguns instantes.
    Se você não consegue carregar nenhuma página, verifique a conexão de rede do computador.
    Se o seu computador ou rede forem protegidos por um firewall ou proxy, certifique-se de que o Firefox esteja autorizado a acessar a web.